# What is the fastest way to convert fields of a json into arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file whose content is as follows, I want to replace the content of each field with arrays.

```
{
    "ID": "GO:0051345",
    "Description": "positive regulation of hydrolase activity",
    "GeneRatio": "3/5",
    "BgRatio": "464/15405",
    "pvalue": 0.000259498331261799,
    "p_adjust": 0.0446337129770295,
    "qvalue": 0.0169356805665595,
    "geneID": "Ptpa/Wdr35/Dnajb11",
    "Count": 3
}
```

I have achieved desired result using the following code:

```
GO_data = fs.readFileSync('my_data.json');
GO_data = JSON.parse(GO_data);
var data_header = Object.keys(GO_data);
// enumerate its property names
for (var prop in GO_data) { 
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(GO_data[prop]);
    GO_data[prop] = arr;
}
//write the converted json
fs.writeFileSync('my_data_arr.json', JSON.stringify(GO_data), 'utf8');
```

content of 'my_data_arr.json' looks like below (as desired),

```
{
    "ID": [
        "GO:0051345"
    ],
    "Description": [
        "positive regulation of hydrolase activity"
    ],
    "GeneRatio": [
        "3/5"
    ],
    "BgRatio": [
        "464/15405"
    ],
    "pvalue": [
        0.000259498331261799
    ],
    "p_adjust": [
        0.0446337129770295
    ],
    "qvalue": [
        0.0169356805665595
    ],
    "geneID": [
        "Ptpa/Wdr35/Dnajb11"
    ],
    "Count": [
        3
    ]
}
```

I would like to learn a better and faster way to achieve the same.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create the array and push into it separately. Just use an array literal with the value in it:

```
for (var prop in GO_data) {
    GO_data[prop] = [GO_data[prop]];
}
```